# Как можно написать свой метод для Object

Tags: javascript, ооп, typescript, класс, telegraf

Имеется вот такой класс:

```
const { Telegraf, Scenes, Context} = require('telegraf'),
      RedisSession = require('telegraf-session-redis');

const ini = require('ini'),
      fs = require('fs'),
      config = ini.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config.ini', 'utf-8'))

class Launcher extends Telegraf{
    constructor(){
        const bot = new Telegraf(config.TELEGRAM.TOKEN)
        const stage = new Scenes.Stage([])
        bot.use(new RedisSession({
                store: {
                    host: config.REDIS.host || '127.0.0.1',
                    port: config.REDIS.port || '6379',
                }}))
        bot.use(stage.middleware())
                super();
                this.bot   = bot
                this.stage = stage
        return bot;
    }
}

module.exports = Launcher
```

И вот такой вот говнокод

```
const Launcher = require('./Modules/launcher')
const bot = new Launcher()

bot.on("message", async ctx => {
    function sendMessage (text, ...argv) {
        this.reply(text, ...argv)
    }

    ctx.sendMessage("text")
    
})
bot.launch()
```

Конечно мне кидает ошибку

```
TypeError: ctx.sendMessage is not a function
```

Но я не могу понять почему оно не работает, если [пример](https://learn.javascript.ru/object-methods#klyuchevoe-slovo-this-v-metodah) работает, а у меня нет.

Я не говорю что `sendMessage` будет только отправлять сообщения. Эта функция будет отвечать за проверку сообшений

- Есть ли старое сообщение от бота?
- Есть ли новые сообшения от пользователя?
- Если есть сообщения от пользователя, то можно ли ему удалть сообщение пользователя и обновить свое старое сообщение
- Есть ли вообще какое-либо сообщение у бота что бы обновит его, или нужно отправить новое сообшение

Comment: При этом `console.log(typeof(ctx))` показал что это `object`

Comment: простите, а зачем вам там определение `sendMessage(text, ...argv) { ... }`?

Comment: @user:189027 я хочу организовать функцию чтобы код понимал что ему отправили `Message` или `CallbackQuery`, а далее определять что ему делать, отправить новое сообщение или отредактировать старое. Это нужно чтобы в чате не было видно старых сообщений

Comment: а `bot.on('callback_query', ctx->{})` чем не подходит?

Comment: и все равно непонятно чем то, что вы делали вам бы помогло

Comment: Там код будет достаточно большой, и каждый раз обращаться к стейту не хочется, а так функция сама все сделает

Comment: ох...не хочу переубаждать

Comment: просто попробуйте последний пример....

Comment: как попробуете - отпишитесь